# Background colours in tikz picture containing tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-feynman

I am trying to split the background colour of the Feynamn diagram below into 2 different colours with (for example) **red in the top half and green in the bottom half**.  Note that both **horizontal lines in the diagram are connected to each other** (the *gluon* line) and therefore, it should remain with a single tikz picture.

Note that, in general, I would like to be able to control the height of each background colour (top and bottom) so they would not necessarily be 50-50.   So far I've only been able to apply a single colour to the entire background as the code below shows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
show background rectangle, 
background rectangle/.style={fill=red}, 
color=black]

\begin{feynman}

\vertex (a1);
\vertex[right=3cm of a1] (a2);
\vertex[below=2cm of a1] (b1);
\vertex[below=2cm of a2] (b2);
\diagram* { (a2) -- [fermion] (a1), (b1) -- [fermion] (b2), (b1) -- [gluon] (a2) };

\end{feynman}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{feynman}

\vertex (a1);
\vertex[right=3cm of a1] (a2);
\vertex[below=2cm of a1] (b1);
\vertex[below=2cm of a2] (b2);
\diagram* { (a2) -- [fermion] (a1), (b1) -- [fermion] (b2), (b1) -- [gluon] (a2) };
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[red] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle 
($(current bounding box.north east)!0.6!(current bounding box.south east)$);
\fill[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
($(current bounding box.north east)!0.6!(current bounding box.south east)$);
\fill[gray] ([yshift=1mm]$(current bounding box.north west)!0.6!(current bounding box.south
west)$) rectangle 
([yshift=-1mm]$(current bounding box.north east)!0.6!(current bounding box.south east)$);
\end{scope}
\end{feynman}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost!  How would you make it so I can control the percentage of the background in red vs green?  Right now the separation is exactly in the middle...

Comment: I updated it. Now its 60% red and 40% blue. By increasing/decreasing 0.6 in `($(current bounding box.north east)!0.6!(current bounding box.south east)$)` you can change the percentage.

Comment: Final thing I see now,  How can you add a third colour?

Comment: @ranlot Where? In between? If so, what percentage? Which color?

Comment: yes, in between.  Let's say gray colour.  Small percentage as kind of a "buffer zone"

Comment: @ranlot Done. If you use that very often, you might want to define a macro for that.